# navigationController:willShowViewController:animated: is not called after popToRootViewControllerAnimated in presented view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

I have `UINavigationController` with several pushed view controllers. 
**UPD:** Last pushed controller modally presents another controller.

Also, I have `UINavigationControllerDelegate` with some logic at `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:`. 
**UPD:** Navigation controller is its own delegate. Delegate is set in `viewDidLoad` method.

**Question** rises when I try to close all controllers programically from presented view controller:

```
// Close all controllers in navigation stack
presentingViewController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

// Close presented view controller
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Method `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` is not called. But it is called when I do the same without presented controller (thanks to @donmag for example project where it works).

Searched SO for answers or similar questions, but found nothing, any thoughts?

Comment: does `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` get called at least ones?

Comment: Where is your `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` function? And where are you setting the delegate?

Comment: @KaterynaGridina Yeah, I mentioned it in question "When I simply use back button on one of my controllers everything works, delegate method is called.". So it gets called when you use back button instead of popToRootViewControllerAnimated.

Comment: @DonMag I don't think it matters because delegate gets called in one case and not in another. But answering your comment: `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` is in my custom `UINavigationController ` class, which implements `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. Delegate is set in `viewDidLoad` of this custom class.

Comment: @eilas - OK, you must have some other code interacting with it.... quick test: subclassed `UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate` implementing `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` ... I get `print()` output from that func every time the current VC changes - on push, pop, Back button *and* popToRoot

Comment: @eilas - here is a simple example project: https://github.com/DonMag/CustomNavController

Comment: @DonMag Thank you very much for example project. It points me that I really have some other code — I have presented view controller which breaks working behavior. I changed question and added other details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your "presenting" VC, you want to implement a delegate/protocol pattern so your "presented" VC can call back and perform the dismiss and popToRoot...

---

```
// protocol for the presented VC to "call back" to the presenting VC
protocol dismissAndPopToRootProtocol {
    func dismissAndPopToRoot(_ animated: Bool)
}
```

---

```
// in the presenting VC

@IBAction func presentTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "presentMeVC") as? PresentMeViewController {
        // Assign the delegate when instantiating and presenting the VC
        vc.dapDelegate = self
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func dismissAndPopToRoot(_ animated: Bool) -> Void {

    // this will dismiss the presented VC and then pop to root on the NavVC stack
    dismiss(animated: animated, completion: {
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: animated)
    })

}
```

---

```
// in the presented VC

var dapDelegate: dismissAndPopToRootProtocol?

@IBAction func dismissTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    // delegate/protocol pattern - pass true or false for dismiss/pop animation
    dapDelegate?.dismissAndPopToRoot(false)
}
```

---

Here's a full demo project: https://github.com/DonMag/CustomNavController

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:
 `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`
Pops all the view controllers on the stack except the root view controller and **updates the display**.

`popViewControllerAnimated:`
Pops the top view controller from the navigation stack and **updates the display**.

So seems like in order to get `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` called every time you have to do subsequent `popViewControllerAnimated:`, because the display got updated each time after you pop a new controller. When you pop to root view controller, update display is called only once.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in comments @donmag pointed that `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` works in simple example. But I have presented view controller after navigation stack which breaks it.